# Problem in downloading torrent file from a college network?

Tags: lan, transmission, utorrent, wifi-direct

Today I have download a `torrent file` in my college from internet, so i decide it to download from college network (LAN / WI-FI) with the `transmission in Ubuntu 18.04`.
15 mins later, downloading status is at 0%.
So i decide to download that `.torrent` file from my phone network and it is starting download.
**Why is that file  not downloading in my college LAN or college WI-FI and how can i download ?**

Comment: It sounds like your college has blocked the downloading of torrents.

Comment: yes.. my college blocked torrent, then how can i use it for downloading ?

Comment: @AbhishekKamal get a VPN.